# Metro UI and C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, zune, microsoft-metro

Does anyone have any code samples in C# that implements the Metro UI? This is similar to the interfaces used in Zune and MetroTwit.

Thanks

Comment: Definitely have a look at [MahApps.Metro](http://www.theleagueofpaul.com/metro-03-released). It is available via Nuget. And was used to update the IlSpy UI featured in [this weeks Channel 9 Show][2] [2]: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/This+Week+On+Channel+9/TWC9-Nov-11-2011

Comment: Look the Microsoft Hello World tutorial for Metro style app...it´s easy: [Building your first Windows Metro style app using C#, C++, or Visual Basic ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx#objectives)

Answer (score 9):

You should check out the [Metro Toolkit on codeplex](http://metrotoolkit.codeplex.com/). It's a open source UI framework aimed at creating UI controls based on Metro.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know of a way to do it without using a WPF application?

Comment: It's  definitely possible to accomplish using WinForms but you'll be writing a lot of graphics code to manually create even the trivial metro effects. Do weigh your time/effort appropriately with that one. My 2 cents.

Comment: Just a heads up Metro Toolkit contained copyrighted XAML code reversed engineered from MetroTwit (my project) and redistributed without permission.

Comment: @LongZheng Side Note..  I love MetroTwit :) !

Answer (score 1):

There are Microsoft Silverlight themes available for the Metro UI.
Cosmopolitan is the one you want, you'll find it via Tim Heuer's blog:

[Tim Heuer's announcements](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/05/03/new-silverlight-4-themes-available-for-download.aspx)

Here is a direct link to blogpost:
[Microsoft download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e9da0eb8-f31b-4490-85b8-92c2f807df9e&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice little jQueryUI Metro theme generator that can be found here: [jQuit Metro Theme Builder](http://jquit.com/builder/)

I have used it and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

This covers the bases of Metro design.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/08/31/designing-for-metro-style-and-the-desktop.aspx